# ffmpeg Non-monotonous DTS Error During Stream copy

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-encoding, matroska, timestamp

I am attempting to stream copy a DTS-HD MA audio stream into the matroska container.

ffmpeg throws Non-motonous DTS errors that look like this: `[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 100, current: 33; changing to 100. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.`

I've tried `-copytb 1` to fix it, I also tried `-fflags +igndts`... anyway, none of the methods I've tried seem to alleviate the issue. How do I fix/prevent non-monotonous DTS errors?

For context; here is my full output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.437]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\henry>ffmpeg -i "D:\Music\The Beatles - Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band (Super Deluxe Edition)\Blu-ray [2017 Stereo & Surround Mix; HD Audio; Extras]\2017 Stereo & Surround Mix.mkv" -map 0:0 -map 0:5 -map 0:1 -c copy -disposition:a:0 default -disposition:a:1 0 "D:\Music\The Beatles - Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band (Super Deluxe Edition)\Blu-ray [2017 Stereo & Surround Mix; HD Audio; Extras]\2017 Stereo & Surround Mix (trim).mkv"
ffmpeg version 4.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.5 : stereo
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'D:\Music\The Beatles - Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band (Super Deluxe Edition)\Blu-ray [2017 Stereo & Surround Mix; HD Audio; Extras]\2017 Stereo & Surround Mix.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libmakemkv v1.14.3 (1.3.5/1.4.7) win(x64-release)
    creation_time   : 2019-04-21T02:28:41.000000Z
  Duration: 00:39:44.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 33174 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 121.921800
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 121.921800, end 287.387100
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 287.387100, end 495.428267
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 495.428267, end 661.861200
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 661.861200, end 820.553067
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 820.553067, end 1025.691333
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1025.691333, end 1185.350833
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 07
    Chapter #0:7: start 1185.350833, end 1493.058233
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 08
    Chapter #0:8: start 1493.058233, end 1652.717733
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 09
    Chapter #0:9: start 1652.717733, end 1818.183033
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 1818.183033, end 1973.004367
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 1973.004367, end 2053.317933
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 2053.317933, end 2384.515467
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 11119444
      DURATION-eng    : 00:39:44.515466666
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 142928
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 3314310394
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001011
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 96000 Hz, 5.1(side), s32p (24 bit) (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.1
      BPS-eng         : 7183618
      DURATION-eng    : 00:39:44.512000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 223548
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2141178116
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001100
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.1
      BPS-eng         : 1509000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:39:44.512000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 223548
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 449778576
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001100
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: truehd, 96000 Hz, 5.1(side), s32 (24 bit)
    Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.1
      BPS-eng         : 8094388
      DURATION-eng    : 00:39:44.515000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2861418
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2412648994
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001101
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.1
      BPS-eng         : 640000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:39:44.544000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 74517
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 190763520
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001101
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le, 96000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 4608 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Stereo
      BPS-eng         : 4608000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:39:44.515000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 71536
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1373480640
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001102
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:6(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 11720
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:01.017683333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1490
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001200
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:7(spa): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 11720
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:01.017683333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1490
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001201
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:8(fra): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 11720
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:01.017683333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1490
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001202
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:9(nld): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 11720
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:01.017683333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1490
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001203
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:10(por): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 11720
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:01.017683333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1490
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001204
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:11(deu): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 11720
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:01.017683333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1490
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001205
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:12(ita): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 11720
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:01.017683333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1490
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001206
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
Output #0, matroska, to 'D:\Music\The Beatles - Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band (Super Deluxe Edition)\Blu-ray [2017 Stereo & Surround Mix; HD Audio; Extras]\2017 Stereo & Surround Mix (trim).mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 121.921800
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 121.921800, end 287.387100
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 287.387100, end 495.428267
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 495.428267, end 661.861200
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 661.861200, end 820.553067
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 820.553067, end 1025.691333
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1025.691333, end 1185.350833
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 07
    Chapter #0:7: start 1185.350833, end 1493.058233
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 08
    Chapter #0:8: start 1493.058233, end 1652.717733
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 09
    Chapter #0:9: start 1652.717733, end 1818.183033
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 1818.183033, end 1973.004367
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 1973.004367, end 2053.317933
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 2053.317933, end 2384.515467
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 11119444
      DURATION-eng    : 00:39:44.515466666
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 142928
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 3314310394
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001011
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 96000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 4608 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Stereo
      BPS-eng         : 4608000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:39:44.515000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 71536
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1373480640
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001102
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA) ([1] [0][0] / 0x2001), 96000 Hz, 5.1(side), s32p (24 bit)
    Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.1
      BPS-eng         : 7183618
      DURATION-eng    : 00:39:44.512000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 223548
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2141178116
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001100
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-21 02:28:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 100, current: 33; changing to 100. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 100, current: 50; changing to 100. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 100, current: 67; changing to 100. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 100, current: 83; changing to 100. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 200, current: 133; changing to 200. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 200, current: 150; changing to 200. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 200, current: 167; changing to 200. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 200, current: 184; changing to 200. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 300, current: 234; changing to 300. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 00000294f0f902c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 300, current: 250; changing to 300. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

. . . . . . .
```

Thanks in advance to those trying to answer my question.

Comment: The issue is with the video stream and apparently its timestamps are out of order.  Try with https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html

Comment: @Gyan I appreciate the advice, but, is there any way to the same thing in ffmpeg? If not, which of the three MKVToolNix programs should I use, and how; what command(s)?